# Trying to wrap an element in a function component but getting Unexpected Token Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use the [Pro-Gallery](https://github.com/wix/pro-gallery) library and wrapping the component generated in a function component but getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at Gallery.js:24:10)` when running it. Am I missing something here?

Gallery.js:

```
import { ProGallery } from "pro-gallery";
import "pro-gallery/dist/statics/main.css";
import React from "react";

export function Gallery(images) {
  // options here...

  return (
    <ProGallery
      items={images}
      options={options}
      container={container}
      eventsListener={eventsListener}
      scrollingElement={scrollingElement}
    />
  );
}

export default Gallery;
```

ImageGallery.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { testImages } from "../../test/index.js";
import Gallery from "./Gallery.js";

interface Image {
  image: string;
  tags: string[];
}
const ImageGallery: React.FC = () => {
  return <>{Gallery(testImages)}</>;
};

export default ImageGallery;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why one file is `tsx` and the other is `js`? Also, that's not how you use React components. Please see [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) about functional components.

Comment: Even though they are Function components you don't ever invoke them. They are still passed to React as JSX components and React handles invoking the functions.

Comment: Yeah I originally tried to just wrap the Gallery.js in a tsx file, but I was looking at examples like https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-6f9ovv?file=index.tsx, and saw this was how people were able to make it work.

Comment: Even I change it to a JSX Component with <Gallery testImages={testImages} />, I get the same issue

Comment: ah nevermind, I found the issue I was able to wrap it in a JSX functional component itself and avoid the .js